# How to modify ie update MySQLx Document Store Data

Tags: mysql, node.js, document-store

I want to update my MySQL document store schema.I am using @mysql/xdevapi for document store.I have referred this link for example [Reference Link](http://insidemysql.com/develop-by-example-document-store-working-with-collections-using-node-js/)

For single field it is working properly.But when i am updating whole object it throws an error as "Provided expression is neither a expression string nor a parse tree".

Single field syntax:-

```
coll.modify("$._id == '100'").set('$.name', 'New name').set('$.description', 'New Description').execute();
```

This is working fine.

Updating object : -

```
var obj = {"name":"New Name"};
coll.modify("$._id == '100'").set(obj).execute()
```

This is not working.

Kindly suggest, is there any other way to do this.

Comment: According to the [Collection.modify() Syntax Diagram](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/x-devapi-userguide/en/collection-crud-function-overview.html#collection-modify), you need to indicate `CollectionField` and `ExprOrLiteral`.

Comment: @wchiquito:- I tried using the syntax given by them as :-  coll.modify("$._id == '100'").set("$.doc",expr(obj)).execute(). But still it is not working.. And "expr is not defined" error is coming...Anything else has to be done ??

Comment: @wchiquito :- Thanks for your comment.. I reached 90% to my solution.Just 1 question more:- While inserting data it is my JSON.parse() object, but while updating the same data JSON.parse() is giving error. Any idea on this ??

Comment: Modify (update) doesn't seem to accept a JSON (`DocumentOrJSON`) as input parameter according to the syntax diagram.

Comment: @wchiquito :- Yes its true. I tried but its not working..We have to update individual fields only using loop